# DJANGO: request.POST.getlist() into ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have been searching online, but have not found anything that would help solve this issue.

Lets say in a view we receive some POST info. We have a ModelForm containing an int and char field. The POST contains a query dict of names and ages.

```
{ 'name': ['John', 'Doe'], 'age': [22, 24] }.
```

How can I get this post info into a ModelForm nicely. 
I do

```
PersonForm(request.POST)
```

which only gets 1 of the set of POST info.

Is there a better solution, rather than just getting a list of the POST fields and putting them into the fields?

Comment: The real solution would be to use [`modelformset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet) if your application is the one generating the POST requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to generate two dicts and use them to initiate two `PersonForm`s.  Something like this:

```
name_age_pairs = zip(request.POST.getlist('name'), request.POST.getlist('age'))
data_dicts = [{'name': name, 'age': age} for name, age in name_age_pairs]
for data in data_dicts:
    form = PersonForm(data)
    form.save()
```